# Bypass Facebook and Twitter inapp browser for my website

Tags: android, ios

I am looking for resources on how I can bypass my website being opened in Facebook and Twitter inapp browsers.  My website uses cookies and user logins and it will be hard to retain users if they have to login in each app they use on their phone.

Is there a way my website can detect that it is currently opened in a non-system browser and trigger a new open in system-browser? I am trying to avoid having to write my own app

The current situation is that links of my website open inside FB and Twitter app separately thereby forcing user to sign in again.